# Customize alert in ionic

Tags: sass, ionic3

I have default call of alert and add CSS class to customize alert

```
presentPrompt() {
let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: 'Login',
  cssClass: 'input-alert',
  inputs: [
    {
      name: 'username',
      placeholder: 'Username'
    },
    {
      name: 'password',
      placeholder: 'Password',
      type: 'password'
    }
  ]
});
alert.present();
 }
```

SCSS

```
ion-alert{
    .input-alert{
        &.alert-wrapper{
            width: 100%!important;
        }
    }
}
```

I need to response the alert to full width, but this method doesn't work.

How can I do this?

Comment: where have you placed your `.input-alert`

Comment: @MohanGopi What do you mean?
in component i think

Comment: place your css inside app.scss file and then try remove your ion-alert part use only `.input-alert`

Comment: @MohanGopi the same effect, its not working

Comment: what version you are using because for me everything works fine as i told before